# Jquery Autocomplete linked list to open in Iframe?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete from http://easyautocomplete.com/ in which I'm using a linked list. The linked list works fine but I would like to open the links in an iframe which is on the same HTML page as the autocomplete dropdown instead of a new webpage. Any ideas of what I should research to get it done or even a solution?

Example code:

```json
[
  {
    "text": "Home",
    "website-link": "link1"
  },
  {
    "text": "Guide",
    "website-link": "link2"
  },
  {
    "text": "Themes",
    "website-link": "link3"
  },
  ...
]
```

UPDATE: I've got now a working linked list and I've nearly got the output directed to an iframe,  I have a working linked list below and I've tried to change the src of a iframe called "myframe". The content of the ifame changes but it shows as "file or directory cannot be found".
Can any one help? I'm sure its something simple!

```
`var data = [`
`{text:'test1', url:'test1.html'},`
'{text:'test2', url:'test2.html'},'
'{text:'test3', url:'test3.html'},'
'{text:'test4', url: 'test4.html'},'
'{text:'test5', url: 'test5.html'}'
'];'
'$('#testautocomp').autocomplete(data, {'
'formatItem: function(item) {'
'return item.text;'
'}' 
'}).result(function(event, item) {'
'});'
'$('#testautocomp').change(function(){'
'$("#myFrame").attr("src", $(this).val(), $(this).attr('url'));'
'});`'
```

Answer (score 0):

On change of your list, use

`document.getElementById('myFrame').src = location; //javascript`

or

`$("#myFrame").attr("src", location); //jquery`

where `location` is "website-link".

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/xpna3ua8/

```js
$("#urlList").change(function() {
   $("#myFrame").attr("src", $(this).val());
 });
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="urlList">
  <option>http://en.wikipedia.org/</option>
  <option>http://www.bing.com</option>
</select>
<br/>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://en.wikipedia.org/"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

These options should do it:

```
var options = {

    list: {
        onSelectItemEvent: function() {
            var link = $("#myInput").getSelectedItemData();
            $("#myFrame").attr("src", link["website-link"] );
        }
    }
};
```